# One site with two different domain name indexed in Google

Tags: seo, google-search-console, search-engines

My site is indexed in google with too different domain names , one with http and another with https . 
I was just wondering that if there is something I should do like trying omit one , or there is no problem and Google will take it .
Thanks.

Comment: We get this question a lot! You should only ever have one. You will likely want to redirect your HTTP site to HTTPS. Otherwise, if you do not redirect one to the other, you should use a canonical tag on your site to indicate only one is to be indexed. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en This will avoid duplicate content issues and allow which ever site you chose to perform properly. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the web is moving to https, you ought to consider forcing all visitors to https.

You can do this by inserting the following code in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However you need to check your site does not have 'mixed content' of http and https.  You will see a secure padlock if everything is OK.  If not, check the console in Developer Tools in your browser.